# Create new instance of class with metaclass in python

Tags: python, metaclass

I would like to create dynamically a new instance of a class with a specific metaclass in python.

I've tried this :

```
type('A', (object,  metaclass=tmp, ), {})
```

but doesn't work :(

Does anybody know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

A metaclass is typically a subclass of `type`, (or perhaps rarely a function taking `name, bases, clsdict` as arguments), so you should be able to use it like `type`. If `tmp` is your metaclass, then try:

```
tmp('A',(object,),{})
```